# How do I bring an already existing open window to the front on top of other windows from another windows code?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, dom-events

The question was fairly descriptive but I'll describe it further.

Basically, I have `window1`. Clicking a button link opens `window2`. Clicking a button in `window2` opens `window3`, clicking a button in `window3` should bring `window2` back to the front of the screen on top of `window2`.

I'm not sure how this is exactly done, however I have used and played around with focus(), opener and other various methods and I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: Quick solution, don't use popups and instead handle it inside the page using layers and a UI library (e.g. jQuery UI Dialogs). Popups are ultra-annoying in this day and age.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Bring window to front if already open in window.open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311293/javascript-bring-window-to-front-if-already-open-in-window-open)

Comment: @MaxShawabkeh, sometimes we don't have alternatives, opening on a modal/dialog prevent user from navigate on site if they aren't on a reactive website or SPA.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:  This hasn't worked since Chrome (21+).  The workaround is to close/reopen.

```
opener.focus()
```

does work. If it doesn't for you, we'll need a test case.

Some things that might cause problems: calling it in an event handler that fires *before* the button's window gets focus due to the click (but I don't think that'd usually be the case); running it on a browser that stuffs pop-ups into browser tabs instead.

(I agree with Max's comment. Pop-ups with cross-window scripting are generally best avoided.)

Comment: window.focus() doesn't work for me either, on a regular basis

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:  This hasn't worked since Chrome (21+).  The workaround is to close/reopen.

The following code works for me on Firefox (Mac & Windows), Safari (Mac & Windows), and IE8 (Windows, of course).  I haven't tested IE6 or IE7.

However, it does *not* work on Chrome for either Mac or Windows.  Specifically, clicking the button once creates the pop-up and brings it to the front.  However, returning to the original window and clicking the button again does not refocus the popup.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var popupWindow = null;
    var doPopup = function () {
      if (popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed) {
        popupWindow.focus();
      } else {
        popupWindow = window.open("http://google.com", "_blank",
          "width=200,height=200");
      }
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="doPopup(); return false">
    create a pop-up
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Re-asked this question specifically for Google Chrome [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703314/in-google-chrome-how-do-i-bring-an-existing-popup-window-to-the-front-using-java)  Please let me know if there's a preferred etiquette for doing so.

Comment: Probs worth checking out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/