# In Firefox, how do I bring an existing popup window with multiple tabs to the front using javascript from the parent window?

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup

I would like to have a button on a web page with the following behavior:

- On the first click, open a pop-up.
- On later clicks, if the pop-up is still open, just bring it to the front.  If not, re-open.

The below code generally works in Firefox, Safari, and IE8 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703314/) for Chrome woes).  However, I have found a failure mode in Firefox that I don't know how to deal with:

If for some reason the user has opened a second tab in the pop-up window and that second tab has focus within that window, the `popupWindow.focus()` command fails to have any effect.   (If the first tab has focus within that window, everything works just great.)

So, how can I focus the popup and the desired tab in Firefox?

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var popupWindow = null;
    var doPopup = function () {
      if (popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed) {
        popupWindow.focus();
      } else {
        popupWindow = window.open("http://google.com", "_blank",
          "width=200,height=200");
      }
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="doPopup(); return false">
    create a pop-up
  </button>
</body>
```