# When using setInterval, if I switch tabs in Chrome and go back, the slider goes crazy catching up

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, slider

I have a jQuery slider on my site and the code going to the next slide is in a function called nextImage. I used setInterval to run my function on a timer, and it does exactly what I want: it runs my slides on a timer. BUT, if I go to the site in Chrome, switch to another tab and return, the slider runs through the slides continuously until it 'catches up'. Does anyone know of a way to fix this. The following is my code.

```
setInterval(function() {
nextImage();
}, 8000);
```

Comment: perhaps you can add a condition to see if the window is focused before u run the nextImage()

Comment: Sorry, how is that done?

Comment: i just saw this on a forum but i don't know if it works if `(window.focus){nextImage();}`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to have worked either.

Comment: @Ibu: `window.focus` is a function, not a boolean. It will likely always be a truthy value.

Answer (score 42):

[How to detect when a tab is focused or not in Chrome with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720658/how-to-detect-when-a-tab-is-focused-or-not-in-chrome-with-javascript)

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    document.title = 'focused';
},false);

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    document.title = 'not focused';
},false);
```

To apply to your situation:

```
var autopager;
function startAutopager() {
    autopager = window.setInterval(nextImage, 8000);
}
function stopAutopager() {
    window.clearInterval(autopager);
}

window.addEventListener('focus', startAutopager);    
window.addEventListener('blur', stopAutopager);
```

Note that in the latest version of Chromium, there is either a bug or a 'feature' which is making this less reliable, requiring that the user has clicked at least once anywhere in the window. See linked question above for details.

Comment: This is quite an easy solution, but I think a `mousemove` & `touchmove` handler would be more suitable for this. So if no activity inside tab for a given time frame, the object should be given no green light to try to fire anything.

Comment: The answer quoted here has been updated and the solution given doesn't seem to work anymore, at least for me. What did work is the updated answer to the quoted question, which is to use the `visibilitychange` event like so: `document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    document.title = document.hidden;
})`. @ninjagecko can you please update the answer accordingly?

Answer (score 16):

I post an answer here: [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/7387953#7387953)

Just do this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#your-image-container").stop(true,true);
    nextImage();

}, 1000);
```

inactive browser tabs buffer some of the setInterval or setTimeout functions. 
stop(true,true) - will stop all buffered events and execute immadietly only last animation.

The window.setTimeout() method now clamps to send no more than one timeout per second in inactive tabs. In addition, it now clamps nested timeouts to the smallest value allowed by the HTML5 specification: 4 ms (instead of the 10 ms it used to clamp to).

Comment: Thank you - I searched everywhere for something that would fix this and this did it.

Answer (score 6):

A few ideas comes to mind:

---

### Idea #1

You can make it so that a short burst is **idempotent**. For example, you could say:

```
function now() {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
}

var autopagerInterval = 8000;

function startAutopager() {
    var startImage = getCurrentImageNumber();
    var startTime = now();

    var autopager = setInterval(
        function() {
            var timeSinceStart = now() - startTime();
            var targetImage = getCurrentImageNumber + Math.ceil(timeSinceStart/autopagerInterval);
            if (getCurrentImageNumber() != targetImage)
                setImageNumber(targetImage);  // trigger animation, etc.
        },
        autopagerInterval
    );
    return autopager;
}
```

This way even if the function runs 1000 times, it will still run in only a few milliseconds and animate only once.

**note**: If the user leaves the page and comes back, it will have scrolled. This is probably not what the original poster wants, but I leave this solution up since it is sometimes what you want.

---

### Idea #2

Another way to add idempotence (while still keeping your `nextImage()` function and not having it scroll to the bottom of the page) would be to have the function set a mutex lock which disappears after a second (cleared by another timeout). Thus even if the setInterval function was called 1000 times, only the first instance would run and the others would do nothing.

```
var locked = false;
var autopager = window.setInterval(function(){
    if (!locked) {
        locked = true;
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            locked=false;
        }, 1000);
        nextImage();
    }
}, 8000);
```

**edit: this may not work, see below**

---

### Idea #3

I tried the following test:

```
function f() {
    console.log((new Date()) + window.focus());
    window.setTimeout(f, 1000);
}
f();
```

It seems to indicate that the function is being called every second. This is odd... but I think this means that the callbacks *are* being called, but that the *page renderer* refuses to update the page in any graphical way while the tab is unfocused, delaying all operations until the user returns, but operations keep piling up.

Also the `window.focus()` function doesn't say if the window has focus; it GIVES focus to the window, and is thus irrelevant.

What we want is probably this: [How to detect when a tab is focused or not in Chrome with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720658/how-to-detect-when-a-tab-is-focused-or-not-in-chrome-with-javascript) -- you can unset your interval when the window loses focus (blur), and reset it when it gains focus.

Comment: Where do I call my nextImage function with this?

Comment: you'd have a function `setImageNumber(num)` rather than `nextImage = function(){setImageNumber(getCurrentImageNumber()+1)}`

Comment: if the `if (!window.focus)` solution works, it is definitely superior to this one, especially since I do not think it is your intent that the user go back and find the page has scrolled all the way down

Comment: Unfortunately the window.focus solution isn't working. I really wish it would for its simplicity. What's annoying about this is that it works fine in all other browsers, and just needs one line of code. I wish I could make it work in Chrome too without needing a lot of extra code.

Comment: @Nathan: my second idea (updated) may work and is shorter, I have a third coming up

Comment: Thank you SOOO much for your help. Idea #2 doesn't seem to do the trick either though unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what is going on in your function nextImage(), but I had a similar issue. I was using animate() with setInterval() on a jQuery image slider that I created, and I was experiencing the same thing as you when I switched to a different tab and back again. In my case the animate() function was being queued, so once the window regained focus the slider would go crazy. To fix this I just stopped the animate() function from queuing.

There are a couple ways you can do this. the easiest is with .stop(), but this issue and ways to fix it are documented in the jQuery docs. Check this page near the bottom under the heading additional notes: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue, somehow this code below works fine for me.

```
            var t1= window.setInterval('autoScroll()', 8000);

    window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        focused = true;
        window.clearInterval(t1);
        t1 = window.setInterval('autoScroll()', 8000);
    },false);

    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        focused = false;
        window.clearInterval(t1);
    },false)



function autoScroll()

    {

        if ( running == true){
            if ( focused = true){
                forwardSlide();
            }


        }

        else {

            running = true;

        }



    }
```

Comment: Your timeout values are 8000ms, so you will not be affected by this problem (no workaround required).  Chrome allows setInteval to be call every 1000ms when tab does not have focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Soh Tanaka's image slider then just add this...to solve your Google Chrome issue:

`$(".image_reel").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300).animate({ left: -image_reelPosition}, 500 ).fadeIn(300);`

Take note of the .stop() function. Ignore the fading in and out stuff, that's what I used on my version

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seconding the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183463/when-using-setinterval-if-i-switch-tabs-in-chrome-and-go-back-the-slider-goes#comment81472983_6184208) by jgerstle to use page visibility events instead, see https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#example-1-visibility-aware-video-playback for more around subscribing to 'visibilitychange' for hidden/visible states.

This seems to be more useful than focus/blur these days as it covers visible-but-not-selected windows if concerned also about multi-window operating systems.