# Blinking tags with javascript, firing off at different times

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am blinking image tags in javascript using jquery.

Here's a simple sample of my code:

```
var timer = setInterval( function(){
    $( leds ).css( 'opacity' ) == 1 ? 
              $( leds ).animate({ opacity: .1 }, 100 ) : 
              $( leds ).animate({ opacity:  1 }, 100 );
}, 500 );
```

But the the images blinking is not in sync, in fact, it is sequential in the order that the `led` array is stored. The difference is quite prominent. Also, over time, the the time it takes to blink appears to increase to upto 2 seconds instead of the original 0.5 seconds.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: [It works OK for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/VT2uB/)

Comment: Hey can you post more code?  Where does that code you posted happen?  I bet the problem is that you're setting up the timer more than once.

Comment: Works for me too on Chrome 12 and IE8/9.  Obligatory raising of the glass in memory of the <blink> tag.

Comment: Wow in Chrome 12 I do get one weird effect - because of the new throttling of timers for non-focused tabs, if I leave the tab and then come back, a whole bunch of "pent-up" animation happens in rapid succession. Adding a ".stop()" call before the ".animate()" seems to help.

Comment: @Pointy: I was testing it on JSFiddle after writing the question as well, and it worked. So not sure what could be causing it. I have more timers on the page for other things, not sure if it's conflicting with those. As to your last question: this may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183463/when-using-setinterval-if-i-switch-tabs-in-chrome-and-go-back-the-slider-goes-c

Answer (score 0):

Probably your explicit setInterval isn't playing nice w/ jquery's animate.  Have you considered looping the animation in some way?

http://www.irengba.com/codewell/