# Flash as javascript interval replacement

Tags: flash, intervals

Hi I am developing a web application which require a consistent interval. However I notice that when the window is loss focus the interval will die.

I wonder if it is possible to embed a flash that sets an infinite looping to cater this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need flash, you should be able to modify your animation code slightly, you just have to do something like this

```
var $div = $('div');

var a = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    a++;
    $div.stop(true,true).css("left", a);
}, 1000 / 30);
```

Inactive browser tabs buffer some of the setInterval or setTimeout functions.

stop(true,true) will stop all buffered events and execute immediatly only the last animation.

The window.setTimeout() method now clamps to send no more than one timeout per second in inactive tabs. In addition, it now clamps nested timeouts to the smallest value allowed by the HTML5 specification: 4 ms (instead of the 10 ms it used to clamp to).

Answers taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/7387953#7387953) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183463/when-using-setinterval-if-i-switch-tabs-in-chrome-and-go-back-the-slider-goes)

Comment: Thanks Varuna for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Varuna for your suggestion. However, I intend to have the interval continues even the window is out focus, which was why flash came to mind. Basically what I have to implement is to replicate record behaviour on looping sounds which requires a persistent interval.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that there are two ways to approach this. First is to use HTML 5 web workers. However ie would not be supported in this case.

The second method would be to limited the interval timer to no less than 1000 ms. It is Bcoz the interval doesnt die but rather stays at a maximum of 1s. Anything more frequence than that would be buffered which is causing problems.