# Nivo Slider Transition Timing Speeds Up After Navigating Away From Browser Tab

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm modifying a jQuery Nivo Slider (jquery.nivo.slider.js) and currently it is set to ~7 seconds a slide and works fine, but if I navigate to another tab on my browser for long enough and go back to that tab the slide image stays for ~7 seconds, but the text cycles through each slide's text at about ~2 seconds timing.

Any reason why this could be? There's a ton of code and I'm not sure what would be relevant to post and what wouldn't be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using setInterval, if I switch tabs in Chrome and go back, the slider goes crazy catching up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183463/when-using-setinterval-if-i-switch-tabs-in-chrome-and-go-back-the-slider-goes)

Comment: Flagged my own question as a duplicate, found answer at duplicate link