# Javascript: How to prevent triggering focus on input when window is focused?

Tags: javascript, html, input, event-listener, onfocus

I have a classic case of an input that is cleared when gaining focus.

The problem is that when user goes to copy some data from a spreadsheet e.g. and comes back to add this data to the input, the focus event of the input is triggered and whatever they typed is cleared.

**How to prevent onfocus from being triggered when it is due to a browser window focus** and not from a click on the input, a tab, the click of a label, or any traditional action in the page?

NO JQUERY PLEASE.

EDIT:
OK apparently some people like to vote negatively every time a post does not have some code. So if you need a code to grasp this simple idea, here it is:

```
<input type=text onfocus="this.value=''">
```

Comment: Why is the data cleared on focus ?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: how can anyone help fix a behavior in code they can't see? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you use onclick event instead of onfocus. Random thought

Comment: but why would it be focused when the window is focused? this only happens with `autofocus` form fields

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 - `onclick` isn't good since a user can change fields using `tab` key or use `tap` event, or who knows what

Comment: @FlorianB - I don't see this happening in this [**Demo page**](https://output.jsbin.com/waxeme)

Comment: @FlorianB - try to make another input with `autofocus`

Comment: @FlorianB - well, at least 2 others needs to verify this. I see no reason for this to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing browser tabs undesirably fires the focus event, especially in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657176/changing-browser-tabs-undesirably-fires-the-focus-event-especially-in-google-ch)

Comment: @FlorianB - if you place another input and give it `autofocus` attribute, does your original input still gets focused?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, switching windows does cause the element to lose/regain focus. This, of course, triggers the `focus` event handler. There's no way to differentiate between what caused the focus event to happen.

If you want to clear the field only when it's manually selected, use the `click` event instead:

```
<input type=text onclick="this.value=''">
```

---

You can detect if the page loses focus. It might be possible to use that to infer whether the `input` should be cleared or not when it regains focus. I'm not sure if event order matters or if event order is different based on the browser involved.

```
<input type=text>
```

```
donotclear = false;

addEventListener('blur',function(e){
  donotclear = true;
});

document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('focus',function(e){
  if(donotclear) {
    donotclear = false;
  } else {
    this.value = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: @FlorianB Updated