# Perform action before "open in new tab" on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a href="/foo/bar">Some Link</a>
```

If I have some link that directs to /foo/bar/, I can do pre-processing with jquery before the redirect, like so:

`jQuery('a').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... Whatever needs to be done
    var newUrl = 'abc';
    window.location.href = newUrl;
});`

Is there any way to propagate this action to when a user opens the link in a new tab?

**Edit:**
When someone clicks into the link, the above javascript will execute, however, if they right-click->Open in new tab, the above javascript will have no affect. How would I apply the javascript even if the link is opened in a new tab?

Comment: can you add more description to your answer is not clear what exactly you are expecting.

Comment: I googled an "unfocus" event for window/tab, it might work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6184276/173299