# Focus tab event Javascript

Tags: javascript

How I can detect when user `focus` in this tab and when user unfocus current tab
I'm trying this **code**:

```
window.onfocus = function() {
    alert('Got focus');
}
```

Why this not work?

Comment: With tab you mean to an HTML element? Are you using a component library?. Or with tab you mean the browser's tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: What browser are you trying this on?

Comment: Also answered perfectly simple by @ninjagecko at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720658/how-to-detect-when-a-tab-is-focused-or-not-in-chrome-with-javascript

Answer (score 4):

The event you are looking for is `visibilityChange` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange

When the event if fired, you can check if the page is visible or not through document[hidden]. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API for a working example.

Comment: Is this a cross browser solution?

Comment: While this works for a lot of cases, it literally tracks visibility, rather than what's focused. So if you have two browser windows open, and select the second one, the event will not trigger. It really depends on the case of course.

Comment: Browser support is indicated at the bottom of the first link, but all recent browser support it yes.

Answer (score 0):

This IS the API for tracking when the current tab gains or loses focus. You can spell it like so, and it will work for almost all browsers. I suggest using the following syntax:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    console.log('Focused');
})

window.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    console.log('Unfocused');
})
```

One reason I can think of for not firing the event is that you're mostly sitting in your browser console. Window does not receive focus or blue events if the dev tools are what you've actually "focused".

Comment: If you could provide a JSFiddle, I'd consider this a more complete answer.

Comment: The result panel should display "Focused" when you click inside it and "Unfocused" when you click outside. This should also work for changing your tab. https://jsfiddle.net/hy9yL2ad/

Comment: Afraid it's not working for me! Version 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit) Chrome.

Comment: Odd, it definitely should work on your version of Chrome. Have you tried attaching other types of events to the window or DOM elements, are you getting results with those? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

For particular HTML element.....

```
 $("#elementId").focus(function(){
       //fire when element is focused...
  });
  $("#elementId").blur(function(){
      //fire when element is unfocused...
  });
```

For window.....

```
$(function() {
    $(window).focus(function() {
        console.log('Focus event');
    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        console.log('un focus');
    });
});
```