# window.focus to bring main window in front of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway some how I can bring popup window behind the main browser and bring the browser window in front.
Here's what I am trying :

```
var w = window.open('google.com','Popup window');
setTimeout(function() { w.blur();window.focus();},100);
```

Works in Firefox after enabling advanced settings for JavaScript. Not for Chrome, Safari and other browsers.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nowadays browsers (and all ad blockers afaik) are tailored to prevent pop-unders (since in 2013 pop-under = spam most of the time), I'd suggest you reconsider your design

Comment: Thanks Erik, Alex.
@ABertil jsfiddle for??

Answer (score 2):

According to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703334/1307594), `window.focus()` won't work on **Chrome** because it is disabled. It might be the same for **Safari**.