# Opened multiple popup using window.open().How to make all popup stay at top and also access parent page

Tags: asp.net, popup, window.open

I have a scenario where I need to open multiple popup almost 5 . If I use window.open() method , I can open multiple popups but it is not staying on top of parent page all the time. After I open first popup , it shows on top of parent page. then when I access parent page to open second popup , first popup goes behind the parent page. Is there any way I can achieve this functionality.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to store the window handles in an array and call the focus method. It works in IE. It will not work in Chrome, details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703314/in-google-chrome-how-do-i-bring-an-existing-popup-window-to-the-front-using-jav)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/baga143/gn33rr12/)

Code below.

```
var popupWindowsArr = new Array();

function popupClicked() {
    var title = "Test -" + popupWindowsArr.length;
    var wndID = window.open("http://www.google.com", title, "height=400,width=700");
    popupWindowsArr.push(wndID);
    for(var i = 0; i < popupWindowsArr.length; i++) {
        popupWindowsArr[i].focus();        
    }
}
```

EDIT - To bring focus to popups after a postback.

One way is store the names of the opened windows in a hidden field and use it. This will work only if the popup url is in the same domain.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPopupNames" runat="server" />


function popupClicked() {
    var popupNames = document.getElementById('<%=hdnPopupNames.ClientID %>').value;
    var wndName;
    if (popupNames.length > 0) {
        var namesArr = popupNames.split("|");
        wndName = "Test -" + namesArr.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < namesArr.length; i++) {
            var wnd = window.open("", namesArr[i]);
            wnd.focus();
        }
        popupNames += "|" + wndName;
    }
    else {
        wndName = "Test - 0" ;
        popupNames = wndName;
    }
    window.open("TestHTMLPage.htm", wndName, "height=400,width=700");
    document.getElementById('<%=hdnPopupNames.ClientID %>').value = popupNames;            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But popupWindowsArr not retaining the popup windows when the page post back.So always it opens the current popup window not all

Comment: Yes. It is very useful. I will try to find out a way for chrome. Because most of our users use chrome. If you find anything, let me know.

Comment: @Mey Sure, will see if I can find anything. If this answer was helpful, pls accept it.