# auto open browser on some event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to open the browser in which my page is there in one tab.
i am running a script like below

```
  function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ //some script }, 10000);
  }
  myFunction();
```

suppose i have minimized the browser before the 10 seconds, and now i am working on another application. i just want that when ever my "some script" runs or any other event fired my browser should automatically open. or atleast browser icon should blink.

i have checked with alert, it works but i dont want this solution.
i want to do it on all modern browser.

thanks in advance.

Comment: [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification)  seems a good fit, but no support in IE.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311293/javascript-bring-window-to-front-if-already-open-in-window-open

Comment: @AnuragSinha thnaks