# how to make browser popup when a javascript triggers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser

I got a javascript that fills in the modal html. I would like after that to maximize the window if it is minimized or to focus that tab if it is maximized and not focused.
Anybody knows how to do it?

Note: I'd like it to also work in older IE if possible if not I am pleased with the new one also

Thank you all!

Comment: [Yet, the question is to be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311293/javascript-bring-window-to-front-if-already-open-in-window-open)

Comment: Should help with browser minimized detection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328665/how-to-detect-browser-minimize-and-maximize-state-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score -2):

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
```

This will open a new window and you can change the url to suit your needs

Comment: This question is not about opening windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: If it helped you then please accept the answer