# Put Firefox on top with javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, html, firefox

Without using a Firefox module or add-on,
is there a simple way in python or javascript to put Firefox browser on top of the Windows screen ?

Basically, I search a method which allows Firefox to be on top when I make some actions

Theoretically, Firefox should be always opened when the method will be called

Thanks for your support

Comment: Nope, there is not.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311293/1531971