# How to open a URL in a new tab if the same URL is not open in any tab of the browser, else focus on the existing tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tabs, window

I am relatively new in frontend, I am trying to open a new url if the button is clicked. My target is if the url is already opened in a seperate tab, then just switch to that tab. Else, open the url in a new tab and switch to it.

I have went through some documentations and stackoverflow solutions, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311293/javascript-bring-window-to-front-if-already-open-in-window-open).

I also added the following code in my class, but it opens a new window always.

```
openOrCloseChildWindow(
        childWindowUrl: string,
        childWindowName: string,
        childWindowFeatures: string
    ) {
        let childWindow: Window | null = null;

        function openChildWindow() {
            // open the child window and give it the specified name and features
            childWindow = window.open(childWindowUrl, childWindowName);

            // listen for messages from the child window
            window.addEventListener('message', onChildWindowMessage);
        }

        function onChildWindowMessage(event: MessageEvent) {
            // check if the message is from the child window, and has the correct format
            if (event.source === childWindow && event.data === 'childWindowAlive') {
                // the child window is still open, do nothing
            } else {
                // the message is not from the child window, or has the wrong format, close the child window
                closeChildWindow();
            }
        }

        function closeChildWindow() {
            // check if the child window is still open
            if (childWindow && !childWindow.closed) {
                // send a message to the child window to tell it to close itself
                childWindow.postMessage('closeChildWindow', '*');
            }

            // stop listening for messages from the child window
            window.removeEventListener('message', onChildWindowMessage);

            // close this window
            window.close();
        }

        // check if the current window was opened by another window
        if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
            // send a message to the parent window to confirm that the child window is still open
            window.opener.postMessage('childWindowAlive', '*');
        } else {
            // open the child window
            openChildWindow();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I could make this code work or if you have any solutions, please suggest.

I was trying to open a new tab if it is not exist, if exist switch to that tab.

I tried some existing solutions which does not work. I also tried to write a solution myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open link in new window or focus to it if already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982593/open-link-in-new-window-or-focus-to-it-if-already-open)

Comment: It does not as I personally tried those and this answer is old, I guess it does not work any more.

Comment: Just to make it short. It's not possible with the exisiting APIs to do this. The other question just proposes some alternatives.